# Proof with mean value theorem

Tags: derivatives

I am having trouble completing this proof.

Prove that $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x-1}{x}=0$$ using the mean value theorem.

The mean value theorem guarantees that we have a c such that $\displaystyle f'(c)= \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$. In our case, we can write $\displaystyle \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{f-0}=f' (c)$. But that is just the definition of the derivative, so I don't see how to go from this to the limit?

Comment: Poor form to use the mean value theorem here. What you have is, *by definition*, the derivative of cosine, evaluated at $0$.

Comment: I am told to use the mean value theorem by the assignment.

Comment: Which doesn't change the fact it is a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: Consider a very small positive $x$, together with $f(x) := \cos x$. Then

$$\frac{\cos x - 1}{x} = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = f'(c) = \sin c$$

for some $0 < c < x$.

Comment: If x is small, the numerator would be close to 1 and the denominator would be very small, so wouldn't the fraction blow up?

Comment: The numerator goes to zero more quickly than the denominator does.